# No such property: scm for class: groovy.lang.Binding in Jenkins ver. 2.107.2.

Tags: jenkins, plugins, version-control, multibranch-pipeline

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: scm for class: groovy.lang.Binding in Jenkins ver. 2.107.2.  Tried to follow some of the posts but I couldn't find any useful info or I might not have followed. If anyone faced same issue please explain how its resolved

Comment: Could you provide more info or sample code about what are you trying.

Comment: See [ask]. What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get? Show your [mcve] and share the exact error message and tracebacks.